A question about grammartical functions of additional words, phrases & clauses in sentences


Wow! What a wonderful day.
Ah, you were there after all!




If he check my story - and he probably will - I will be sacked.
The manager -and her secretary- have been charged with defamation.
I'm convinced it was mastermind by by Tom - or Ginger, as everyone calls him.
They will be finishing on Tuesday -or at least that's what they said.
They go - probably - by bus.
They'd given me two diskettes, both of which turnel out to be defective.
There are ,I think , some for optimism.
The editor has been sacked and, worse, they're imposing strict censorship.
Jill - and I don't blame her- left before the meeting ended.
Sue felt -can yoy blame her?- that she was being exploited.
Jill sold her internet shares in January - a very astute move.
Bizet's most popular opera, 'Carmen', was first produced in 1875.




He is honest , isn't he?


What are grammartical function of these bold words, phrases & clauses?
In modern grammar, these are called supplements.
But I need to know its traditional grammartical functions. Because I mostly follow traditional grammars.
I know that it's too long. But it is urgent to know these.

Your question is off-topic, not because it is too long, but because (i) there's no focus and (ii) you have done no research. This site is for answering questions about a specific point of learning English. We don't do your homework for you.

The noun is grammar, but the adjective is grammatical (no 'r').  And I think I've already told you that names (Tom, Ginger, Carmen) always start with a capital letter,

I'm not sure how you're differentiating "modern grammar" and "traditional grammar". So far as I know, "supplement" in the context of syntactic analysis simply refers to "words, phrases, and relative clauses that add extra information to a sentence", but which can be added or removed without affecting the syntactic validity of the sentence. I'm not aware of the term being peculiar to "modern" grammar. But imho it's not a particularly useful category anyway. Your first two examples feature interjections, and most of the rest are parentheticals in my way of looking at things...

...but Carmen in the final example looks more like a proper noun in apposition to me. Probably different syntactic frameworks use a range of different terms here.

The first two are interjections. There's a fun song about them in Schoolhouse Rock.
